# MySQL sort on year/month/day

Tags: mysql, date, sorting, strip

I have a large list of dates of the format `dd-mm-yyyy.`
So I want to order on: year, then on month and then on day.

Date and month are in the same field and year is an other field.

I have now: `ORDER BY table.year ASC, table.date ASC`

The result is that the list is order on year and then days.
How to split/strip the dd-mm format and first sort on month before sorting on days?

```
Same record:    
date | year   
dd-mm  | yyyy
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

based on your example you can sort the record like this,

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year, '-', date), '%Y-%d-%m') ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95f5a9/1)

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge it's better to use single date type field instead of having seperate two fields for date-month and year as you can easily sort your results.

According to your query date-month can be stripped out using RIGHT(date-monthfield, 2) function. This selects month which is on the right side.

The query would be:

```
select RIGHT(date-monthfield, 2) from table ORDER BY date-monthfield ASC;
```

Hope it helps.