# Mysql sort by date but ignore year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has a Mysql `DATE` field type.

I am searching the entries and need to sort the entries soonest first within the next 30 days. BUT, some of entries will have years on them which have now expired as it is recurring data.

For the date find I'm using `DAYOFYEAR` which works great.

Question is: Can I sort the following into least number of days until the event, first?

```
select b.name, ue.event_title, ue.event_date from brains b
join user_events ue on b.user_id=ue.user_id
where b.user_id=63 and 
MOD(DAYOFYEAR(ue.event_date) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) + 365, 365) <= 30 
order by event_date desc
```

**`order by event_date desc` is where it goes wrong because of year**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299109/mysql-sort-on-year-month-day

Comment: How is that relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

**Answer**

```
select b.name, ue.event_title, ue.event_date,
(DAYOFYEAR(ue.event_date) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE())) as days
from brains b
join user_events ue on b.user_id=ue.user_id
where b.user_id=63 and 
MOD(DAYOFYEAR(ue.event_date) - DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) + 365, 365) <= 30 
order by days asc
```